# PHP doesn't connect with MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

This code is supposed to get the information from a simple HTML form and post in into a MySQL database:

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>Cadastro de Cinema</title>
<head>

<body>
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$banco = "cinema";
$con = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die(mysql_error());

?>

<?php

$email= isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$senha= isset($_POST['senha']) ? $_POST['senha'] : '';
$nome= isset($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome'] : '';
$rua= isset($_POST['rua']) ? $_POST['rua'] : '';
$bairro= isset($_POST['bairro']) ? $_POST['bairro'] : '';
$numero= isset($_POST['numero']) ? $_POST['numero'] : '';
$cidade= isset($_POST['cidade']) ? $_POST['cidade'] : '';
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO cinema(email, senha, nome, rua, bairro, numero, cidade)
VALUES ('$email', '$senha', '$nome', '$rua', '$bairro', '$numero', '$cidade')");

echo "OK";
?>
</body>

</html>
```

When I test it, I get the "OK" echo, but the info is not in the mySQL database. What could it be?

Comment: Please stop using the `@` that will never help you learn.  If the connection is failing fix it, dont hide the error.  Dont use variable in queries, you are open to SQL injections; look at parameterizing your query and prepared statements. Also `mysql_error` wont help with `mysqli` errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you submit your database here. So, we can check if the table/data type is supported by this query or not. Please try this:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Cadastro de Cinema</title>
<head>

<body>
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$banco = "cinema";
$con = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $banco) or die("Could not connect to database. " . mysqli_connect_error());
?>

<?php

$email= isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$senha= isset($_POST['senha']) ? $_POST['senha'] : '';
$nome= isset($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome'] : '';
$rua= isset($_POST['rua']) ? $_POST['rua'] : '';
$bairro= isset($_POST['bairro']) ? $_POST['bairro'] : '';
$numero= isset($_POST['numero']) ? $_POST['numero'] : '';
$cidade= isset($_POST['cidade']) ? $_POST['cidade'] : '';
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO cinema(email, senha, nome, rua, bairro, numero, cidade)
VALUES ('$email', '$senha', '$nome', '$rua', '$bairro', '$numero', '$cidade')");

echo "OK";
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Simple Database Table I Used:

```
CREATE TABLE `cinema` (
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `senha` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `rua` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `bairro` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `numero` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cidade` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have an error here

```
    $banco = "cinema";
    $con = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die(mysql_error());
```

The name for your db is `$banco`, but you have used `$db` in your query. Change to

```
$con = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $banco) or die(mysql_error());
```

You have assigned `mysqli_query` to a variable `$sql`, this means that it has not been executed. Do

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Cadastro de Cinema</title>
<head>
<body>
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$banco = "cinema";
$con = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die(mysql_error());
?>

<?php
$email= isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$senha= isset($_POST['senha']) ? $_POST['senha'] : '';
$nome= isset($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome'] : '';
$rua= isset($_POST['rua']) ? $_POST['rua'] : '';
$bairro= isset($_POST['bairro']) ? $_POST['bairro'] : '';
$numero= isset($_POST['numero']) ? $_POST['numero'] : '';
$cidade= isset($_POST['cidade']) ? $_POST['cidade'] : '';
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO cinema(email, senha, nome, rua, bairro, numero, cidade)
VALUES ('$email', '$senha', '$nome', '$rua', '$bairro', '$numero', '$cidade')");
//I have removed the assignment    
echo "OK";
?>
</body>

</html>
```

or if you want to check whether the operation was successful, do

```
$sql=mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO cinema(email, senha, nome, rua, bairro, numero, cidade)
VALUES ('$email', '$senha', '$nome', '$rua', '$bairro', '$numero', '$cidade')");

if($sql)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: I think your heading down a rabbit hole but one step to avoid that is `mysql_error()` will not work with `mysqli`.